# Can a helicopter fly VFR at night in India?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, dgca-india

As per the title, can a helicopter fly VFR at night in India?.
If yes, can the pilot ask for special VFR?

Comment: I  know in the Netherlands (and that would mean the rest of EASA territory) you'd need an additional certification on top of your PPL to be allowed to do night VFR, irrespective of aircraft type. You should check that with your license authorities as well.

Comment: So what I understood from your answer is that helicopter can fly VFR as icao guidelines, just we have to check for any certification from licence authority Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, a helicopter can fly at night, in the US.  Special VFR requires that the aircraft and pilot be instrument capable, but that requirement is not applicable to helicopters.  VFR weather minima are different for helicopters than airplanes.

Comment: Sir please give references with respect to ICAO documents.

Comment: I am so sorry.  I answered for the US, not knowing that your question domain was India.  I am not familiar with India's regulations.  ICAO Annex 2, 3.6.2.4(c), chap 4 covers VFR, in general. Table 3-1 has helicopter weather minima.

Comment: Thanks for reference